# Destroy a session of another user in spring

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, sessionid

In my application, I have an admin that can delete users. so when I delete a user from the admin session I want that the deleted user should get logged out automatically.
I know the user's session id whom I delete but I don't know how to invalidate a session using the session id.

I would like something like: invalidate(SessionId);

Is it possible in any way? I think it is possible using a filter and checking the database every on request but is there another way where I don't need check the db on every httprequest?

Thanks. :D

Comment: May I know how you can retrieve the user's session id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I see a solution using the Spring Security infrastructure, with the [SessionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) class.

You have to register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in the `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In your Spring config, declare the SessionRegistry.

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
     class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

In your administration console, you have to use the `SessionRegistry` to retrieve the `SessionInformation` of the user and call `expireNow`. At the next request of the user, a servlet filter should make the HttpSession expire. The javadoc of [SessionInformation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionInformation.html) has some explanation about how it works.

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: I am having problems, I registered the session calling *sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(String session, Object principal)* when I delete the user, I get the session correctly and I call *sessionInformation.expireSession()* in the controller but it didn't worked. the session of the user it is still working

Comment: I read the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) again, and I think you also have to add `<session-management ...>` to the `<http>` section of your Spring security config. I hope it will help.

Comment: Why not to add this to the answer?

Answer (score 7):

```
// to end a session of a user:
List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistryImpl.getAllSessions(user, false);
sessionRegistryImpl.getSessionInformation(sessions.get(0).getSessionId()).expireNow();

// note: you can get all users and their corresponding session Ids: 
List<Object> users = sessionRegistryImpl.getAllPrincipals();
List<String> sessionIds = new ArrayList<>(users.size());

for (Object user: users) {
    List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistryImpl.getAllSessions(user, false);
    sessionIds.add(sessions.get(0).getSessionId());
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do what LaurentG wrote?

Comment: @Alex78191, our answers are pretty much the same. In both cases you need to call `expireNow` method.

Comment: Should i register the `HttpSessionEventPublishe` in the `web.xml` and declare the `SessionRegistry`?

Comment: Can't remember that. I was using not web.xml but rather java config.

Comment: I believe you may want to expire the user's session as above, but also remove them as well (removeSessionInformation(sessionid).

Answer (score 0):

Along with what has been suggested by @LaurentG, following needs to be added in your spring config file :

```
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" />
</session-management>
```

for it to work. Also @zygimantus answer can be used for accessing the session data.

Comment: `<concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" />` is the same as `<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to expiring the user as described, you may also want to remove them from the registry:

```
// expire and remove the user's sessions from Spring session registry
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
for (Object principal : principals) {
    List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, true);
    for (SessionInformation sessionInfo : sessions) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal().equals(sessionInfo.getPrincipal())) {
           if (!sessionInfo.isExpired()) sessionInfo.expireNow();
           sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInfo.getSessionId());
        }
    }
}
```

And if using xml config to wire up your Spring Session Registry, it may look something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```