# kill server sessions spring

Tags: java, spring, session

I have an application based on spring framework.
This application allows 2 multiple sessions for each user.

```
<bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <property name="expiredUrl" value="/faces/pages/templates/error.xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="2" />
                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I need that when I login with the second session, kill the first session.

I am tried this with expireNow method, but the 2 sessions maintain active.

```
        authenticate = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getResponse();

            sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authenticate, httpReq, httpResp);

            final Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            final org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    username, password, grantedAuthorities);

            List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, false);
            if (sessions.size() > 1) {
                sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessions.get(0).getSessionId()).expireNow();


sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessions.get(0).getSessionId());
                }
```

How can I make this!

Thank you.

Comment: Then why in the first place do you want 2 concurrent sessions... You basically want a single one.

Comment: Because if I have 1 sessions only, when I try login on another place, I will be blocked, and I need that when I login on another place, close the first session and login in the second place.

Comment: That depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see [Destroy a session of another user in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107703/destroy-a-session-of-another-user-in-spring). I hope this helps. Specially look for comment about `<session-management ...>` in the `<http>` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting something like the following before your login code.

This should expire the sessions for that particular user (**authentication.getPrincipal()**) that are not already expired and then remove them from the Spring Security session registry:

```
// expire and remove the user's sessions from sessionRegistry
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
for (Object principal : principals) {
    List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, true);
    for (SessionInformation sessionInfo : sessions) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal().equals(sessionInfo.getPrincipal())) {
           if (!sessionInfo.isExpired()) sessionInfo.expireNow();
           sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInfo.getSessionId());
        }
    }
}
```