# which class check valid http request in spring

Tags: java, spring

i currently facing a problem. I want to kick out a user A when they are on their session. I tried by cleared user A's session, but this didnt work because my application runs in multiple nodes. 
My solution now is creating a filter ( which i put position = "LAST") to catch all the requests from user A, and then i can log this user out. But the problem is all invalid requests are going to this filter, this is not good for my service. So i want to find a way to do the same filter after spring check all the valid request. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I tried by cleared user A's session, but this didnt work because my application runs in multiple nodes. Can you elaborate this a little more? How you cleared and how you are managing tokens?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, following question may have solution to your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337997/how-to-add-custom-filter-after-user-authorize-in-spring-application

Comment: @MohamedAneesA i used sessionRegistryImpl to destroy session of a user. See more in here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107703/destroy-a-session-of-another-user-in-spring)

Comment: @Channa Thank you for your answer. But my filter is already behind authorized filter. The invalid request that i mentioned is 404 request.